# How to limit access of Project Owner

Tags: gerrit

is there a way in Gerrit to either:

1. Limit access of Project Owner to read-only
2. Make certain API calls while not being a Project Owner. To be more specific, I'm interested in two calls:

   `GET projects/<project_name>/branches/<branch>/reflog/`
   and
   `GET projects/<project_name>/commits/<commit>`

We have a few developer teams in the company, that could really benefit from Gerrit API, but we are trying to limit the access for the obvious reasons. So far we've created a group, "Devs A", where we added all the developers and then added that group to Project Owner. Then we blocked `refs/meta/config` privilege for "Devs A", but the group members are still able to edit/delete repositories and branches. Any idea on what else should we block?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Why did you grant "Project Owner" permission to the "Devs A" group? If you want to let the group GET branches and commits endpoints you only need to grant "Read" permission to "refs/*".